# using ternary for returning a color resource with annotaion @ColorInt android

Tags: java, android, annotations, ternary-operator

I have two code for the same funtionality.

---

**Code 1**

```
@ColorInt
int getColor(@ColorRes int id) {
    if (getActivity() == null) {
        return Color.BLACK;
    } else {
        return ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), id);
    }
}
```

---

**Code 2**

```
@ColorInt
int getColor(@ColorRes int id) {
    return getActivity()==null?Color.BLACK:ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), id);
}
```

The first code snippet doesn't gives an error but the second one gives an error **should pass resolved color instead of resource id** and when i remove the **@ColorInt** annotation the second code works fine, can someone help why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

`ContextCompat.getColor` method dose not annotated with `@ColorInt`.
So Lint tools occurs that error.
[Here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.java#L363-L370) is source code of `ContextCompat.getColor`.

Lint tools checks the method's annotations at below codes.

- [SupportAnnotationDetector.checkColor()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_2.0.0/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/SupportAnnotationDetector.java#420)
- [SupportAnnotationDetector.getResourceTypes()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_2.0.0/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/SupportAnnotationDetector.java#978)

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=209756&can=1&q=Should%20pass%20resolved%20color%20instead%20of%20resource%20id%20here&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) is same bug report.